# How to Bind Two Properties to the Detail Property of TextCell

Tags: xamarin

In my code-behind, I created a **RecentSearches** class with the following properties:

```
public class RecentSearches
{
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string CheckIn { get; set; }
        public string CheckOut { get; set; }

}
```

I created a generic list of that type and instantiated it to the following values. **lvRecentSearches** is a ListView object in the XAML code.

```
lvRecentSearches.ItemsSource = new List<RecentSearches>
{
    new RecentSearches
    {
        Location = "West Hollywood, CA, United States",
        CheckIn = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"),
        CheckOut = new DateTime(2016, 11, 1).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"),
    },
    new RecentSearches
    {
        Location = "Santa Monica, CA, United States",
        CheckIn = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"),
        CheckOut = new DateTime(2016, 11, 1).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"),
    }
};
```

In XAML, I want to set the Detail attribute of the TextCell to both the *CheckIn* and *CheckOut* properties. Is this possible or should I combine them in the code-behind?

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRecentSearches">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Location}" Detail="{Binding CheckIn}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would simply be to create a 4th property,

`public string CheckInAndOut { get { return CheckIn + " " + CheckOut; } }`

And then bind this property to the TextCell's Detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a custom `ViewCell`, and then use it in the `DataTemplate`. It's pretty well explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell/). This allows you to customize a cell template and therefore bind any kind of data you want into it. You could easily add two labels next to each others for the checkIn/CheckOut properties.

Note that usually `TextCell` performs better due to the rendering process. If your goal is only to regroup 2 properties in a single one while keeping the look and feel of the `TextCell`, I would suggest doing it in code behind and then bind this new property to the `Detail` property. Because in your case custom `ViewCell` is probably a lot of work (i.e. custom renderers) for no big added value.

Comment: Why not use a Converter that converts two into one?